# Ignore lines in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list called **reassembly** organized like this:

```
['AFLT', 228468.0, 'B'],
['TATN', 1108.6, 'B'],
['TATN', 4434.4, 'B'],
['MOEX', 3480.0, 'S'],
['YNDX', 5934.0, 'B'],
['MTSS', 36003.0, 'S'],
['SBERP', 33837.1, 'S'],
['SBERP', 1780.8, 'S'],
['MTSS', 3273.0, 'S'],
['AFLT', 124356.0, 'B'],
['AFLT', 20244.0, 'B'],
['MGNT', 72990.0, 'B'],
['NLMK', 230917.0, 'B'],
['NLMK', 156050.0, 'B'],
['NLMK', 31220.0, 'B'],
['MGNT', 36450.0, 'S'],
['TCSG', 14045.2, 'S'],
['TCSG', 2160.4, 'S'],
```

Also there is a dictionary called **medians** with data:

```
{'TATNP': 11968.05, 'TCSG': 8647.2, 'TRNFP': 130250.0, 'UPRO': 7941.0, 'VTBR': 3828.28, 'YNDX': 17660.4}
```

Keys in dictionary are equivalent to first values in list ( 'AFLT', 'VTBR' and others)

I convert **reassembly** to pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(reassembly, columns=['ticker','vol','operation'])
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
df = df[df['vol'] < median['ticker']]
```

I mean if vol < median for this ticker script should ignore it.

Help me please to write this code correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `map`:

```
high_volumes = df[df['vol'] > df['ticker'].map(medians)]

# do suff with high volume transaction
```

Note that the above can fail if you don't have all the `tickers` in `medians`. In which case, let say you want to keep  all those `tickers` that are not in `medians`:

```
meds = df['ticker'].map(medians)
high_volumes = df[(df['vol']>meds)|(meds.isna())]
```

Comment: It works!!! How can complicate it: df['ticker'].map(medians) multiplied by x? I mean medians['ticker'] * x

Comment: If `x` is a number, do `meds = df['ticker'].map(medians) * x`.

Answer (score 2):

`df = df[df['vol'] > df['ticker'].map(median)]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest solving this with a list comprehension and pipe the result into panda instead.

```
reassembly = [['AFLT', 228468.0, 'B'],
['TATN', 1108.6, 'B'],
['TATN', 4434.4, 'B'],
['MOEX', 3480.0, 'S'],
['YNDX', 5934.0, 'B'],
['MTSS', 36003.0, 'S'],
['SBERP', 33837.1, 'S'],
['SBERP', 1780.8, 'S'],
['MTSS', 3273.0, 'S'],
['AFLT', 124356.0, 'B'],
['AFLT', 20244.0, 'B'],
['MGNT', 72990.0, 'B'],
['NLMK', 230917.0, 'B'],
['NLMK', 156050.0, 'B'],
['NLMK', 31220.0, 'B'],
['MGNT', 36450.0, 'S'],
['TCSG', 14045.2, 'S'],
['TCSG', 2160.4, 'S']]

medians = {'TATNP': 11968.05, 'TCSG': 8647.2, 'TRNFP': 130250.0, 'UPRO': 7941.0, 'VTBR': 3828.28, 'YNDX': 17660.4}

ready_for_panda = [x for x in reassembly if x[0] in medians and x[1] > medians[x[0]]]

pd.DataFrame(ready_for_panda, columns=["ticker", "vol", "operation"])
```

```
ticker  vol      operation
TCSG    14045.2  S
```

I have assumed that you want to filter out any element from reassembly where the volume is less than the current median for this ticker.

Comment: in general list comprehension is slower than pandas' vectorized functions.